# Display two subreports side by side

Tags: view, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-2011

I have two subreports which get displayed when I give my selection criteria, one after the other.

Can I change the layout of those pages so the pages get displayed side by side? That would make it easier to view both in a single glance. (I am using Crystal Reports 2011.)

Comment: place sub reports side by side

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell from your question, but it sounds like you want the printed pages to alternate between the two subreports. Such that when you print out the pages and read it like a book, you'll get Subreport 1 on the left page and Subreport on the right. That's not something Crystal would be able to do easily.

However, if you just want the subreports to print side-by-side on the *same page* that's ridiculously easy! It's as simple as resizing and moving the subreports as if they were just ordinary elements on the report:

[image]